Cómo puedo obtener el audio de un usuario en un canal de voz en discord.py?
Estoy creando una herramienta que ayude a los discapacitados visuales a poder usar la app de Discord. Me surgió una idea de hacer Speech Recognition en un canal de voz a una persona con un rol específico, convertirlo a texto y mandarlo por el chat. Además, hacer que la respuesta que tenga un comando lo hable por el canal de voz usando la API de gTTS. Aquí está mi código, no ligado a Discord.
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Comienza a hablar...")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
        print("/{}".format(text))
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="es", slow=True)
        tts.save("test.mp3")
    except:
        print("No se reconoció lo que dijiste")```

